# how to send a copy to another email address of all incoming messages from an email account?(postfix)

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

how to send a copy to another email address of all incoming messages from an email account?(postfix)

it's possible?

thx.

Answer (score 15):

You can simply use [recipient_bcc_maps](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#recipient_bcc_maps) to copy all emails being sent to a specific user (or a specific domain).

For example add the following line to your `main.cf` (or use `postconf` for that):

```
recipient_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps
```

and create a file `/etc/postfix/recipient_bcc_maps` with the following content:

```
user@example.com  recipient@example.net
```

and run `postmap recipient_bcc_maps`.

Comment: And don't forget to issue 'service reload postfix' or 'systemctl reload postfix', whether your distro uses systemd or not. Otherwise postfix will not use the newly postmapped file

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by creating *two* aliases for the account, as follows:

Let's say you have two email addresses: mom@example.com and kid@example.com, and you want mom to get a copy of all of kid's email. In this case, mom@example.com and kid@example.com would both be accounts, but you would *also* create the following aliases:

```
From:                         To:
kid@example.com               mom@example.com
kid@example.com               kid@example.com
```

Postfix will understand this -- the kid -> kid alias does not create a loop (though it looks like it should!), instead it tells Postfix to continue on to delivering to the mailbox even though the mail was already delivered to the alias.

Comment: Note that postfix complains about a duplicate entry. Put both `mom@example.com` and `kid@example.com` destination on the same line.

Comment: It surprisingly works.

Comment: Works like charm. I've been looking for a solution to this problem for months.

Answer (score 1):

one solution is to use procmail a different solution is to use ~/.forward file. over the two procmail has far more options and control.

Comment: i fount it:

http://www.minigeek.org/2007/11/postfix-archive-emails-via-bcc

Comment: send bcc will do it as well ... :) there is also an option into main.cf

Comment: could u tell me how to use this second option?

Comment: check this link - is quite simple if you still have problems let me know - http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Procmail_-_setup_with_postfix

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using this milter if your postfix storage format is mbox: http://www.dancingfortune.com/projects/archivesmtp/index.php

the advantage is that if a user is authenticated and not using the proper from details his mail will still be caught by this milter while the sender_bcc_maps won't catch it.